# Unable to convert avro data back to spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, serialization, deserialization, spark-avro

I have a dataframe as such

```
raw_df.show()
raw_df.printSchema()
```

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
+---+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I am able to convert this dataframe to avro using spark-avro's `to_avro` function with the following schema like so.

```
schema_v0 = """
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Value",
  "namespace": "bets",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "bets.Value"
}
"""
encoded_df = raw_df.select(to_avro(F.struct(*raw_df.columns), 
                                   jsonFormatSchema=schema_v0
                                  ).alias("avro_encoded_value"))
encoded_df.show()
```

```
+------------------+
|avro_encoded_value|
+------------------+
|           [02 61]|
|           [02 62]|
|           [02 63]|
+------------------+
```

However, when I try to convert this avro encoded data back to a spark dataframe using another schema with an optional+nullable column called `redeemed`, I am getting a `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing.`

```
schema_v1 = """
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Value",
  "namespace": "bets",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "redeemed",
      "type": ["boolean", "null"],
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "bets.Value"
}
"""
decoded_df = encoded_df.select(from_avro("avro_encoded_value", schema_v1).alias("avro_decoded_value")).select("avro_decoded_value.*")
decoded_df.show()
decoded_df.printSchema()
```

As I understand, the default value should be used when decoding and used to fill in the default value if it is absent in the encoded data correct? Why is this not happening? For reference, I am using Spark 3.4.1 & org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.4.1